# How to parallelize converting a gzipped csv to parquet using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a large gzipped csv file to parquet using PySpark. I am fairly new to PySpark. The following is my code. I am running this code in a Google Cluster with 1 master and 2 worker nodes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
ss = SparkSession(sc)
spark = ss.builder.appName("Conversion-to-Parquet").getOrCreate()

# read csv
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(
    "gs://bucket/test.csv.gz")

# Displays the content of the DataFrame to stdout
df.show(10)

df.write.parquet(
    "gs://bucket/parquet/output.parquet")
```

I don't exactly know how to use parallelise function in spark context for this task. Can someone help me? This activity takes around 5 mins to run and the GZipped file is around 1.7gb in size. I need to know if i can do this task in less time and how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The read will not be parallelized since GZIP is a non-splittable compression codec.You can check the number of partitions of `df` using `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` and the increase/decrease the partitions according to your cluster using either `repartition` or `coalesce`.

Comment: @philantrovert Thanks for the answer. I added the following code `rdd = df.rdd.repartition(4)` but still the number of partitions are are shown as 1.